# UICollectionView crashing on insertSections, with endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add a new section to my collection view, as a new section's worth of data is added to the data source. I'm doing it like this:

```
self.conversationCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    self.conversationCollectionView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0))
}, completion: {
(finished: Bool) -> Void in
})
```

I started by not using `performBatchUpdates`, too. Either way, I get this crash, every time:

```
Assertion failure in -[MyApp _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:]
```

This is after running the line `insertSections`.

I have more than 0 indexes. I've tried changing that index number to other values, including the correct value. I get the same crash, every time. It doesn't seem to be an 'out of bounds' kind of error. I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you update your

`UICollectionViewDataSource`

function

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView`

According to your new section count?

Comment: this will not solve all kinds of problems like this. I have a collection view that has one section and crashes sometimes with this same error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, when the collection view wasnt the top most view.

Comment: Same issue. really frustrating